# Wordpress: how to apply alphabetical filter function?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, frontend

I`m having a bad time trying to get my shopping cart list alphabetically ordered.
I know I need to use a filter function like this:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'am_woocommerce_catalog_orderby');
function am_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $args ) {
    $args['orderby'] = 'title';
    $args['order'] = 'asc';
    $args['meta_key'] = '';
    return $args;
}
```

But I dont know how to use it in here:

```
<?php
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
                $_product     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                $product_id   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) )
                {
                    ?>
            <div class="row cart-item-row">
                <div class="col col-sm-2">
                    <?php
                        if ( $_product->is_sold_individually() ) {
                            $product_quantity = sprintf( '1 <input type="hidden" name="cart[%s][qty]" value="1" />', $cart_item_key );
                        } else {
                            $product_quantity = woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
                                'input_name'  => "cart[{$cart_item_key}][qty]",
                                'input_value' => $cart_item['quantity'],
                                'max_value'   => $_product->backorders_allowed() ? '' : $_product->get_stock_quantity(),
                            ), $_product, false );
                        }

                        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', $product_quantity, $cart_item_key );
                    ?>
                </div>...
```

I will appreciate so much any kind of help,
Thank you!!

Comment: So you want to alphabetize the cart?

Comment: Yes, I want to alphabetize the way the cart´s items are displayed in the list